# how to change default color of column graph using GemBox version 37.3.30.1160

Tags: gembox-spreadsheet

how to change default color of column graph using GemBox version 37.3.30.1160.

If I create a .xlsx template and save the same it will work but I am trying to save the file as PDF and that's where its not working.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 2019-11-15:**
In newer versions of GemBox.Spreadsheet (version 4.5 and above) we added support for chart formatting, [see the version history page](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/articles/gbsversionhistory).

You can find [Excel Chart Formatting example here](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/examples/c-sharp-vb-net-excel-chart-formatting/306). Also, here is another example in C# that shows how to change color of various chart parts like series, background, text, etc.

```cs
ColumnChart chart = ...
chart.SelectData(worksheet.Cells.GetSubrangeAbsolute(0, 0, 12, 1), true);

var red = DrawingColor.FromName(DrawingColorName.Red);
var green = DrawingColor.FromName(DrawingColorName.Green);
var blue = DrawingColor.FromName(DrawingColorName.Blue);

chart.Series[0].Fill.SetSolid(blue);
chart.Series[0].Outline.Fill.SetSolid(red);

chart.Fill.SetSolid(green);
chart.PlotArea.Outline.Fill.SetSolid(red);
chart.Outline.Fill.SetSolid(red);
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**
GemBox.Spreadsheet currently does not have an API support for chart components styles. This information is currently supported only through a preservation and that is why it works for XLSX file, but the preserved information is lost when the input and output file format are not the same and that is why it does not work for PDF files.

However note that we do intend to implement this sometime in the future and if interested please feel free to vote for [this feature](https://support.gemboxsoftware.com/feedback/view/further-chart-support) in order to boost its priority.

But at this moment I cannot tell you exactly when it will be implemented.